# I can ping, but cannot traceroute or connect to VNC

Tags: networking, ping, remote-access, vnc, traceroute

I am trying to connect to a remote computer using VNC.
As I try to connect using VNC, my connection always times out.

(I use the Remmina REmote Desktop in Ubuntu, and the server desktop is a mac configured to receive VNC connections)

I have tried to ping the address, it is always successful. traceroute on the other hand also times out, unless I do an ICMP (i.e. $traceroute -I  )

Does anybody have an idea on how to figure out what is preventing the connection?
(any further tests I can do on either computer, or any settings I need to change on either one?)

Comment: I think this question belongs to superuser.

Answer (score 2):

The Port you are using for VNC is blocked apparently. The reason your ping request works is that pings do not need a port.(Based of what the RFC fact sheet says, therefore, pings will always go through unless you block ICMP requests.).

Just unblock, or allow the specific VNC port and you should be fine.